# Сравнить и найти последние даты, показать только эти строки

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть даты в первом столбце таблицы:

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td>01.12.2013 21:08:52</td>
 <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>19.10.2014 1:13:12</td>
 <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>19.10.2014 1:53:12</td>
 <td>...</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Нужно показать только последние по дате (д.м.г., без сравнивания времени) строки.

**Обновление**

Не являюсь учащимся и задание не является учебным, все для понимания и сводится к практике работы с парсингом и датой на JS.

```
$('table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)').each(function() {
  if($(this).text() != last){
    $(this).closest("tr").hide();
  }
});
```

Как произвести парсинг даты оптимально и сравнить?

Comment: @aliokero, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно дату разбить на составляющие, и собрать объект Date.

```
19.10.2014 1:53:12
```

Сначала по пробелу можно разбить на массив из двух элементов: даты и времени. Время игнорируем, а составляющие даты разбиваем уже по точкам:

```
.split(" ")[0].split(".")
```

Это даст массив из трёх элементов: день, месяц, год. Их можно скормить в [конструктор объекта Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
new Date( parts[2], parts[1], parts[0])
```

Из него можно забрать кол-во микросекунд с начала unix эпохи (целое число) методом `getTime()`.

Надо один раз пробежаться по всем строкам `<tr>` таблицы, брать в них первый `<td>` и вытаскивать из него тот таймстэмп, собирая уникальные значения в массиве. Его потом отсортировать и забрать наибольшее значение - самый свежий день.

Теперь этот таймстэмп надо перевести в строку даты в вашем формате, дописав "0" перед одноцифренными датами и месяцами, и получить строку-образец типа "19.10.2014".

Пробежавшись ещё раз по всем строкам, скрыть те, в которых дата (после опять разбиения по пробелу) не равна образцу.

[Рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/2yz456np/).

Comment: Спасибо большое, от души!